# Passing an array from Spring Boot to Reactjs via postmapping only returns the first object

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am working on a reactjs with Spring Boot Server.
When making a postmapping calling from reactjs via axios to retrieve a list of object, somehow i am only able to get the first object, with the other objects showing only the id. code as follows:

**React Side**

```
    checkAllOffer(){
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/post/getAllOffer/"+ this.state.id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })

    }
```

**Spring Boot Side**

> Controller method

```
    @PostMapping("/post/getAllOffer/{id}")
    public List<Offer> checkOwnOffer(@PathVariable("id") int postId)
    {

        CarPosting currentPost = cpservice.findCarPostById(postId);
        List<Offer>allCurrentOfferForCurrentPost =  currentPost.getOffers();
        return allCurrentOfferForCurrentPost;
        

    }
```

spring boot prints out the data fine

[image: springboot image]

But on the console side, logging the details shows that there are missing information from object 2

[image: Google Console log]

Comment: what is the output of `JSON.stringify(response.data)`?

Comment: nothing appears. not even the first object in the array

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it by removing the @JsonIdentityInfo from the offer entity class.